# Parse Save - Android: save multiple rows

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am stuck with Parse and an OnClick button. The first click works just fine and onclick, the value is added to the database, but it seems like multiple clicks don't work and won't result in the function addPoints() below being properly ran. In fact, the Toast is printed at every click but the database is modified only once and only one row is added (instead of as many rows as many clicks)

```
  clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addPoints(user);

                    }
                });

                }

                private void addPoints(String user) {
                    points.put("points", 10);
                    points.put("business", x);
                    points.put("user", );;
                    points.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 Points added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Any idea how to solve this? 
Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Parse put will update the value in the data base , it won't add the value to the existing one. 
you need to get the value first from the database and then add to it 10 .